# Is there any way to see or enable viewing of Update Notes in the Marketplace? 

Tags: store

Something that has always bothered me in the Marketplace is that I cannot see any update info from the developer of an app when the app is ready for update. All I see now is the same write-up that is on the apps purchase page.

I like this feature, as I generally like to see what an update includes, if for nothing more than interests sake. For example, it is nice to know that a community requested feature has been added to an app, or that a common problem has finally been fixed.

Is there any way to see or enable viewing of Update Notes in the Marketplace?

Comment: 3 answers all within 1 minute of each other. Now that is response time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to view those notes unless they are explicitly added by the developer.

Developers can choose to publish them and they will be included in the description of the application. If you are not seeing anything then the decision was made to not include them. If any contact information is provided you can always try to reach out and ask what has changed.

Being an enthusiast mobile app developer I agree with your intention of the question. It is good practice to provide information on the updates in the about field, for several reasons.

## 1. Let the user know what has changed

To the courtesy of your users, a developer should provide information on what changed on updates. In other professional software developments you can never change an application without letting the user know what the scope of the change is. This is especially important if some functionality have changed, which change the user experience or workflow sequence. On mobile the user will be notified if the app starts to use other services than before.

## 2. Communicating a serious intention

As a phone app user I can often differentiate serious app developers from not so serious ones. It all boils down to **trust** of the application and the developers, since Marketplace is often the only source I have to validate the app. How can I tell if this app is not only useful but is also trustworthy and do not harm my phone? Of course Microsoft checks the app before submission to the public, but on can never be to certain. In my humble opinion a credible update log of changes is more trustworthy than no log at all.

## 3. Convention

It is more and more becoming a convention among mobile app developers to include an update log. When you update applications which was developed from serious mobile application producers like Rovios Angry Birds or Microsoft Skype, there is an update log (or release notes) accompanied.

Comment: No offense, Benny, but this isn't really a helpful answer. In fact, I don't even see an answer here. All you did was agree with the OP, and post reason *why* it is a good idea. Can you please re-word this to be an **answer** to the question, and not why including update notes is a good idea?

Comment: @Joe None taken :-). My answer isn't an exact answer on OP question, but it brings background to update notes on apps in markets. I could elaborate and extend the answer by saying **"No, there is none"**. But since I left it in a comment as well as "between the lines" of my answer, I'll leave the answer as is, if you don't mind. However, since this is a community driven content, anyone can edit the answer to improve it if they feel something is missing.

Comment: @Joe You made a great edit and I appreciate it very much. I was a bit cranky yesterday and I appologize for that. Sorry Joe :/

Comment: no worries, man :)

Comment: This is a great answer! Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

It is up to the developer to publish his release notes. Some do; some don't.

When you are looking at the application in the marketplace, tap 1Show Details` and go to the bottom. In my anecdotal experience, most of the time the release notes are there.

Sorry, but it really is up to the developer.

Answer (score 1):

The developer is free to choose whether he does this or not. Some don't include details on what changed, others include that information at the bottom of their description / details. Some might even let people know in a different channel (their website, forum, blog, ...).

So, if you want to know what updates an app gets, try to stay in contact with the developer if it isn't listed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common practise for the developers to add this to the application notes. however they decide what text is included in there.

Another common practise is to show the release notes in the about screen. again this is the choice of the developer.

There is no official location or place where developers/publishers can add these notes.